# How to run a program to monitor a directory 24/7 and raise an event

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I need to write a program that monitors a directory and raises an event when a file is added to the directory. This task needs to run all the time. I know how to use FileSystemWatcher to implement the task itself, but I don't know how this program that I'll be writing can run all the time. What sort of project template in Vistual Studio should I use to create this program and how I can run this program all the time? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of Visual Studio you are using. Choose the Project Template "Windows Service". Windows service is a computer program that operates in the background similar to Unix Daemons.